# Salesforce dependency are missing ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.salesforce' in MWAA

Tags: pip, airflow, mwaa

I have set requirements.txt file with required dependenices as below.
apache-airflow==2.8.1
boto3==1.34.57
pandas==2.2.1
apache-airflow-providers-salesforce==5.6.2

but still getting below error in MWAA.
Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/upload_data_to_s3.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/upload_data_to_s3.py", line 4, in 
from airflow.providers.salesforce.hooks.salesforce import SalesforceHook
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.salesforce'
any idea or suggesttion how to resolve this.

Thank you,

Comment: Did you go through _all_ the steps described here? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/working-dags-dependencies.html#working-dags-dependencies-how